# How to get polyline coordinates React-Leaft-Draw plugin?

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet, leaflet.draw, react-leaflet-draw

I use this plugin to draw lines on Leaflet map in my project:

https://github.com/alex3165/react-leaflet-draw

I want to get coordinates (lat,long) of drawn polyline, when _onCreate or later. How could i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I agree, the documentation is a bit lacking, so I hope this helps anyone else trying to do this. You first implement an `onCreated` function that is registered on the `<EditControl>` component. You can then access the current `layer` object and its `layerType` from the `event` object that gets passed to this callback.

Depending on the shape type, you can access the coordinates of the shape via a the methods provided by Leaflet (e.g. [circle](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circle)). See code below.

```js
export default DrawTool({prop1, prop2) {
  
  const onCreated = (e) => {
    if (e.layerType === 'circle') {
      console.log("circle center, radius =", e.layer.getLatLng(), e.layer.getRadius())
    } else {
      // polygon & rectangle
      console.log("polygon coordinates =", e.layer.getLatLngs()) // array of LatLng objects
    } // marker or lines, etc.
    // map.addLayer(e.layer) // might need?
  }

  const onDelete = (e) => {
    // do something with e.layer
  }

  return (
    <EditControl
      position='topright'
      onCreated={onCreated}
      onDeleted={onDeleted}
      ...
    />
  )
}
```